# SpringBoot: Attach json on POST request with params

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to make a `POST` request with params and attaching a JSON content.

Up to now:

```java
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8983/solr/arxius/update");

List<BasicNameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commitWithin", "1000"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("overwrite", "true"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wt", "json"));

String json = "...";
// here I need to attach json as body...

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    client.close();
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here `curl` like request:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/arxius/update?_=1605619902909&commitWithin=1000&overwrite=true&wt=json'
  -H 'Content-type: application/json'
  --data-raw $'[{ "id": ... }]'
```

Comment: Are you forced to use apache http client? Otherwise, you can use spring's rest template

https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [StringEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html):

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json, org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding.UTF_8);              
httpPost.setEntity(se);
```

> A self contained, repeatable entity that obtains its content from a String.

For parameters use `URIBuilder`:

```
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder("http://localhost:8983/solr/arxius/update");
uriBuilder.addParameter("commitWithin",  "1000");
...
HttpHost httpPost = new HttpHost(uriBuilder.getHost(), uriBuilder.getPort(), uriBuilder.getScheme());
```

Comment: What about params?

Comment: @Jordi Use `URIBuilder` when creating `HttpPost` and add each param: `uriBuilder.addParameter("commitWithin", 
"1000")`

Comment: Is there any elegant way to add `Content-type: application/json` without writing them literally?

Comment: @Jordi I don't know of a more elegant way